# Uploading code to production server

Tags: linux, sftp

I've been trying to find a way to effectively upload code to my production server. My dev server is on my local machine, so config files are different. Ideally, I'd like to find a command line client that used sFTP and only uploaded files that had been modified.

I googled my brains out today, but have yet to find a solution to this. I'd greatly appreciate any ideas or software recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/). This uploads only changed files. You can then exclude config files based on the extensions from the copy.

Answer (score 1):

I use git and the server hooks feature for this sort of thing.

The transport is over ssh.  Deploying is a git push.

On the server the git pushes go to a bare repository kept private in a user directory.  A hook causes a token to be left for cron.  Another cron task for a different user picks up the token and git pulls the private bare repository into a deployment directory.   This may be a bit Rube-Goldberg for some, but it works for me.

A side benefit of this approach is because the deployment directory is distinct from the bare repository, it is possible to do a git diff in the deployment directory and see if anything interesting has changed...

To get into details, creating a bare empty repository on the server (see man git-init, --bare) will create a name.git directory that you can check out on your dev machine with git pull and copy everything into and then push back to the server.  On the server, in name.git/hooks, post-commit and post-update do "echo hello >/tmp/something" to leave a token for cron.  In the crontab, another cron script looks for this file and if it finds it, does a git pull.  It could do other things too, e.g. if compatibility tweaks are important.